# How to get next minute of the time?

Tags: groovy

```
def waktusekarang   
SimpleDateFormat abc = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm")
waktusekarang = abc.format(new Date())
```

if current time is 13:58, then it will be become 1358 because (`SimpleDateFormat` is `HHmm`). then how to +2 minutes to the current  time then the result become 1400.

i try `new Date()+2` but its not success and the result become 13581,and i also try to `parseInteger`  but its not success too.

please help my problem , how can i +1 or +2 minutes to current time if current minute is 59.because if minute is 59 then +1 will be 60 ,it must be 00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use `format(Date)`. Use `format(int)` and then call `System.currentTimeMillis()` and add 120000 ms = 2 mins. Thats a way to do it without calendar. But you should think of using calendar.

```
SimpleDateFormat abc = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
waktusekarang = abc.format(System.currentTimeMillis()+120000);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use can use Calendar to add minutes to your time, appropriately your time would be incremented:

```
SimpleDateFormat abc = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);
String waktusekarang = abc.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(waktusekarang);
```

Comment: where can i find this Calender?
Groovy:unable to resolve class Calender

Comment: @akiong you've tagged it under Java and it's very much there

Comment: @akiong what about this? http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Calendar.html

Answer (score 4):

A Groovy solution would be:

```
Date in2mins = use( groovy.time.TimeCategory ) {
    new Date() + 2.minutes
}

String waktusekarang = in2mins.format( 'HHmm' )

println waktusekarang
```